# meaning : mssql_rows_affected returns -1?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

This might be a very silly question. 
I am trying to execute a query using PHP and MSSQL.

```
BEGIN 
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 = 170 AND Col2 = 'Test') 
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2) 
VALUES(170, 'Test') 
END
```

when called `mssql_rows_affected()` after executing the query it returns `-1`.

When I execute same query on database directly I get message `Command(s) completed successfully.` That means my query have no errors (though it is not affecting any records).

Additionally return code for the query is `1` (I hope that means query executed successfully)

I have looked on [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-rows-affected.php)  but it says `Returns the number of records affected by last operation`. It doesn't mention what if it returns `-1`.

Does anybody know what `mssql_rows_affected() = -1` means?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Ganesh.

Comment: Can we assume that you have included the `$link_identifier` in the `mssql_rows_affected()` like `mssql_rows_affected($link);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, No I'm not using `$link_identifier`

Comment: ext/mssql is a mess. Depending on the environment it can use a couple of different back-ends, with slightly different and undocumented and/or undefined behaviour. The Sybase [docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ocs_12.5.1.dblib/html/dblib/CHDDEAEG.htm) for the underlying `DBCOUNT()` call suggest -1 would indicate an error state, or that you executed a SP that does not `SELECT` anything. Maybe removing the (unnecessary) `BEGIN..END` block would make difference? If not, look at the result of [`mssql_get_last_message()`](http://php.net/mssql-get-last-message)